# How to authenticate hyperledger user from webportal?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I can successfully run the fabrics example to query/insert to ledger.

I want to build a nodejs web portal and I already directly wrapped query.js in my web app code.

Now the question is, how to authenticate a user the webportal? Since the example query.js has code like:

```
 ...
 return fabric_client.getUserContext('user1', true);
}).then((user_from_store) => {
        if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled())
            //successfully authenticated user1
```

I noticed the cert/private key/pub key files in

```
/hfc-key-store
   user1-cert
   user1-private.key
   user1-public.key
```

Do I need to post any of the keys through parameters or do I create a separate regular username password control?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion you can create a normal login system for the web portal using a database to store the credentials of the users.

In this database you can associate the user to a specific key, which is retrieved each time the user successfully login in the web portal.

In this way, you will have two different levels of authentication:

- one associated to the web portal (username and password)
- and the other one associated to the blockchain (the certificate to
  write and read).